# Is there anything that represent FutureBuilder widget in the React Native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, flutter

I want to retrieve data from Firebase in the React Native, but while taking data, I want to show first loading screen to user, then I want to show data inside of the text. We can easily do it with using FutureBuilder widget in Flutter, but How can I make this in the React Native?

**Here you can see the FutureBuilder widget function**

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: You could make a hook that combines useState and useEffect to listen to a promise

Answer (score 0):

In react `Suspense` can be used

```
<Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
  <SomeComponent />
</Suspense>
```

As everything in react **fallback** misnamed, means **loading**, while SomeComponent loads, it will show Loading component.

Here is some writings about [Suspense](https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense) .